# Nested Text element onPress has no effect, why is that?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am developing a React Native app with React-Navigation v5.

I have a component in which I use hook `useNavigation`. In this component there is a `Text` element in which there is a nested `Text` element, the nested `Text` declared a `onPress` prop, pressing it should navigate user to the `DetailScreen`:

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
...

const MyComponent = () => {
    // use the hook
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    // create a custom element that has nested Text element
    const MyText = () => {
      return (
        <Text>
          Go to
          <Text
            onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("DetailScreen");
          console.log('PRESSED...');
        }}>
            Detail
          </Text>
          .
        </Text>
      );
    }

    return (
    <View style={styles.myStyle}>
      <MyText />
    </View>
  );

};

export default MyComponent;
```

Then in one of my screens I use the above component:

```
import MyComponent from '../components/MyComponent';
...
return (
   <>
    <View style={styles.theStyle}>
       <MyComponent />
    </View>
     
   </>
);
export default MyScreen;
```

In App.js the above screen is used as part of the `Stack.Navigator`. so does the `DetailScreen` :

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="MyScreen">
      <Stack.Screen name="MyScreen" component={MyScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="DetailScreen" component={DetailScreen} />
      ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
```

When I run the app, `MyScreen` is shown along with `MyComponent`. But the nested text in `MyComponent` doesn't navigate user to the `DetailScreen` when pressing on it . That console log `console.log('PRESSED...');` is not shown either.  Basically there is no effect at all when pressing on the "Detail" text. Why the nested `<Text>` is not clickable?

Comment: Are you sure the text is clickable at all? Can you try logging something to the console on press to check if that is the case?

Comment: @giotskhada you are right, the text is NOT clickable. Why is that then?

Comment: It is clickable https://reactnative.dev/docs/text. Try passing the onClick handler to the parent <Text>.

Comment: @Konstantin the parent Text is not supposed to be clickable, that's our requirement of feature,  what I want to achieve is like a line of text "Go to Detail" in which only "Detail" is highlighted and clickable by user.

Comment: Then I think your best bet would be to put TouchableOpacity as a wrapper for the nested text, not sure why you can't trigger it, might be because some other view is occupying place and the handler is not called.

Comment: `onPress` works for nested text on both platforms. Your function is probably crashing on navigation.navigate part or something, or you just fail to see console.logs. Also `const MyText = () => {` creates a new type of component every render which is not what you want. It should either be made a simple function or extracted as a separate component

Comment: It can be problem with your styles (maybe zIndex), because your code is working as intended here: https://snack.expo.io/@vgoroshevsky/407e27